# Find many columns values total in laravel blade Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table named 'courses'. I want to show 'first_line','second_line' and 'third_line' points total for each course for each user who purchased one or more courses from my courses table,individually.
Here is my 'courses' table-
[image: courses]

And my output is-

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I tried something like bellow in my controller, but I could not pass the '$totalPoints' variable to blade to show the totalpoints, I think this is the wrong way. What should I do for getting the right result? Please someone help me-

```
public function showCourses(){
            if ($user_name = Sentinel::getUser()->user_name) {
                    $mycourses = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('buy_courses', 'users.user_name', '=', 'buy_courses.user_name')
                    ->join('courses', 'courses.course_name', '=', 'buy_courses.course_name')
                    ->select('buy_courses.course_name','courses.amount','courses.first_line','courses.second_line','courses.third_line','buy_courses.user_name')
                    ->where('users.user_name', $user_name)
                    ->get();
                //total points for affiliates
                $line_points = DB::table('courses')
                                ->select('first_line','second_line','third_line')
                                ->first();

                $totalPoints = $line_points->first_line + $line_points->second_line + $line_points->third_line;

            }

           //dd($totalPoints);

            return view('courses.show',['mycourses' => $mycourses],['totalPoints' => $totalPoints]);
        }
```

Comment: first of all its give you totalpoints of first record only from the table
and you can use 'compact' for send multiple value to your view

Comment: @md Rashedul not forget to upvote the right answer :)

Comment: Already I did.@kunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. You can try this after getting all courses in controller:-

```
public function showCourses(){
        if ($user_name = Sentinel::getUser()->user_name) {
                $mycourses = DB::table('users')
                ->join('buy_courses', 'users.user_name', '=', 'buy_courses.user_name')
                ->join('courses', 'courses.course_name', '=', 'buy_courses.course_name')
                ->select('buy_courses.course_name','courses.amount','courses.first_line','courses.second_line','courses.third_line','buy_courses.user_name')
                ->where('users.user_name', $user_name)
                ->get();
            foreach($mycourses as $key => $getcourse){
                $mycourses[$key]->total_points = $getcourse->first_line + $getcourse->second_line + $getcourse->third_line;
            }

        return view('courses.show',['mycourses' => $mycourses]);
    }
```

Now you don't need to pass the total Points separately. NOw total points is added in mycourses key. When you print in blade like this-

```
@foreach($mycourses as $course)
   Course Name : {{$course->course_name}}
   First Line : {{$course->first_line}}
   Second Line : {{$course->second_line}}
   Third Line : {{$course->third_line}}
   Course Fee : {{$course->amount}}
   All Total Points : {{$course->total_points}}
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass multiple variable to the view, use compact inside with(). Something like this

```
$mycourses = something;
$totalPoints = something;

return view('courses.show')->with(compact('mycourses','totalPoints'));
```

**EDITED ANSWER BELOW**

if you want to sum the columns. you can use sum().

I would suggest you to start using eloquent relationship that would ease the work.

Create a model for the course and do something like this.

```
$total_first_line = Course::sum('first_line');
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I am getting first total for my all courses, I think for $line_points query using first(), But I want to get total points for every course individual, what should be the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
return view('courses.show',['mycourses' => $mycourses],['totalPoints' => $totalPoints]);
```

here, the second parameter is an array. But in your case, you have passed multiple arrays, which is wrong. So change it to:

```
return view('courses.show',['mycourses' => $mycourses, 'totalPoints' => $totalPoints]);
```

Comment: Now I am getting same total points for my every courses causing of $line_points query first(),what should be the right query for getting individual courses total points?

Answer (score 0):

This line below in your code :

`$line_points=DB::table('courses')->select('first_line','second_line','third_line')->first();`

will always return the first row of the table, if you want to get all the records you should do this instead

`$courses = DB::table('courses')->get();`

and then in the view you can count the total points for each course like below :

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    Course Name : {{$course->course_name}}
    First Line : {{$course->first_line}}
    Second Line : {{$course->second_line}}
    Third Line : {{$course->third_line}}

    Course Fee : {{$course->amount}}

    Total Points : {{$course->first_line + $course->second_line + $course->third_line}}
@endforeach
```

Something like that, hope it helps